# Rails Time objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time, controller

I've got a quick-add action in my events controller, as the client really only schedules events at three different time slots in a given day. Date and Time are working fine with the default form, but trying to set the values by hand are giving me some trouble.

```
def quick_add #params are date like 2012-04-29, timeslot is a string

timeslot = params[:timeslot].to_sym
date = params[:date].to_date

@workout = Workout.new do |w|
  w.name = 'Workout!'
  w.date = date
  case timeslot
  when :morning
    w.time = Time.local(w.date.year, w.date.month, w.date.day, 6)
  when :noon
    w.time = Time.local(w.date.year, w.date.month, w.date.day, 12)
  when :evening
    w.time = Time.local(w.date.year, w.date.month, w.date.day, 18, 15)
  else
    w.time = Time.now
  end
end
```

The events are getting created, the dates are correct, but times are:

```
Morning: 2000-01-01 10:00:00 UTC 
  Expected: 2012-05-02 06:00:00 UTC -400
Noon: 2000-01-01 16:00:00 UTC 
  Expected: 2012-05-02 12:00:00 UTC -400
Evening: 2000-01-01 22:15:00 UTC 
  Expected: 2012-05-02 18:15:00 UTC -400
```

It's worth noting that running the commands in rails console seems to get the results I'd expect.

Comment: Is there a mistake in your sentence "The events are getting created, the dates are correct, but times are:"? Dates are incorrect, times are correct.

Comment: Maybe `params[:date].to_data` isn't giving you the expected result???  Check the request params to make sure `params[:date]` is correct.

Comment: I'm storing date in a separate field which is working correctly. The time object is what  having trouble with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time values are stored in UTC/GMT (+0) time zone as an integer so that no time zone data has to be stored with it. Rails always stores times in the database as UTC times. When you read them out, you'll want to convert them back to your local time zone again.

You can use `time.getlocal` to convert it to your local time zone.